# How to get the class name of the text to verify at run time in Selenium Java Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I need to get and print the Class name `class="community-wrapper bg-blue-dark"` for the text "Selenium Java" like wise for Selenium Webdriver, Selenium Demo and Selenium Learning.

```
String classname = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*contains[@text() = "Selenium Java")).getAttribute("class");

System.out.println(classname);
```

1. Help needed to print all the Class names preceding to the text Selenium Java in console.
2. Help need to print specific class name `class="community-wrapper bg-blue-dark"` in console.

HTML:

```html
<div class="test-content test-GridColumn test-GridColumn--default--12">
   <div class="community-wrapper bg-blue-dark">
  <div class="row align-center small-align-center large-px4 medium-py5 px1 py2 large-py4">
     <div class=" columns large-10 xlarge-8 medium-11 small-12">
        <h3 data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="0" class="text-white aos-init aos-animate" style="font-weight:300;">
           <p><i>Selenium Java</i></p>
        </h3>
        <h6 data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="100" class="text-white text-bold aos-init">
           Selenium Webdriver
        </h6>
        <h5 data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="200" class="text-white text-bold aos-init">
           Selenium Demo
        </h5>
        <p data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="300" class="text-white aos-init">
           Selenium Learning
        </p>
     </div>
  </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: <div class="test-content test-GridColumn test-GridColumn--default--12">
    
        
            <div class="community-wrapper bg-blue-dark">
                <div class="row align-center small-align-center large-px4 medium-py5 px1 py2 large-py4">
                    <div class=" columns large-10 xlarge-8 medium-11 small-12">
                     <h3 data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="0" class="text-white aos-init aos-animate" style="font-weight:300;">
       <p><i>Selenium Java</i></p>

                        </h3>

Comment: Continuation:<h6 data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="100" class="text-white text-bold aos-init">
                         Selenium Webdriver
                        </h6>
                 <h5 data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="200" class="text-white text-bold aos-init">
                         Selenium Demo
                        </h5>
      <p data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="300" class="text-white aos-init">

Comment: Continuation:Selenium Learning
                        </p>
                        
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
  
</div>

Comment: Please help on getting class name.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code :

```
List<WebElement> itemList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div/*[@data-aos='fade-up']"));
for (WebElement element : itemList) {
        if (element.getText().contains("Selenium Java")) {
            System.out.println("Selenium Java" + element.getAttribute("class"));
        } else if (element.getText().contains("Selenium Webdriver")) {
            System.out.println("Selenium Webdriver" + element.getAttribute("class"));
        } else if (element.getText().contains("Selenium Demo")) {
            System.out.println("Selenium Demo" + element.getAttribute("class"));
        } else if (element.getText().contains("Selenium Learning")) {
            System.out.println("Selenium Learning" + element.getAttribute("class"));
        } else {
            System.out.println("not expected label" + element.getText());
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To print the value of the *class* attribute with respect to the texts *Selenium Webdriver*, *Selenium Demo* and *Selenium Learning* you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibilityOfElementLocated()` and you can use the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using the text *Selenium Java*:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//i[text()='Selenium Java']//ancestor::div[3]"))).getAttribute("class"));
  ```
- Using the text *Selenium Webdriver*:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//h6[normalize-space()='Selenium Webdriver']//ancestor::div[3]"))).getAttribute("class"));
  ```
- Using the text *Selenium Demo*:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//h5[normalize-space()='Selenium Demo']//ancestor::div[3]"))).getAttribute("class"));
  ```
- Using the text *Selenium Learning*:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//p[normalize-space()='Selenium Learning']//ancestor::div[3]"))).getAttribute("class"));
  ```

Comment: I need to get the class name by passing text Selenium Java as input. Could you please help.

Comment: @KrishnamuthyTM Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.